# Using 'in' to test for part of one sublist in another in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

Newbie here trying to search for part of one sublist within another sublist.

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5]]

for item in list_1:
    for otherItem in list_2:
        item[0:2] in otherItem[0:2]
```

I was hoping this would return

```
True
False
True
False
True
False
```

But instead I get false for every iteration.
In a nutshell:

```
list_1[0][0:2] == list_2[0][0:2] #this returns true
list_1[0][0:2] in list_2[0][0:2] #this returns false
```

I guess I don't understand how `in` works. Can anyone school me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`in` looks to see if one sublist is an *element* (not sublist) of another list:

```
[1,2] in [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

would be `True`.

```
[1,2] in [1,2,3]
```

would be `False` as would:

```
[1,2] in [1,2]
```

However:

```
[1,2] == [1,2]
```

would be `True`.  Depending on what you're actually trying to do, `set` objects might be useful.

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [3,2,1]
d = [1,1,1]
e = set(a)
len(e.intersection(b)) == len(a)  #True
len(e.intersection(c)) == len(a)  #True -- Order of elements does not matter
len(e.intersection(d)) == len(a)  #False
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your example lists:

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5]]
```

This works:

```
print [this[0:2]==that[0:2] for this in list_1 for that in list_2]
[True, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Or, use a set:

```
print [this for this in list_1 for that in list_2 if set(this[0:2])<set(that)]
[[1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]
```

Be aware that a set is without order, so:

```
>>> set([1,2])==set([2,1])
True
```

A typical use of `in` is with a string:

```
>>> 'ab' in 'cbcbab'
True
```

Or a single element in a sequence:

```
>>> 100 in range(1000)
True
```

Or an atomic element in a sequence:

```
>>> (3,3,3) in zip(*[range(10)]*3)
True
```

But over lapping list element do not work:

```
>>> [1,2] in [0,1,2,3]
False
```

Unless the elements are the same atomic size:

```
>>> [1,2] in [0,[1,2],3]
True
```

But you CAN use a string to compare list a being 'in' list b like so:

```
>>> def stringy(li): return ''.join(map(str,li))
...
>>> stringy([1,2,9][0:2])
'12'
>>> stringy([1,2,9][0:2]) in stringy([1,2,5])
True
```

So your original intent MAY be to check to see of `item[0:2]` appears anywhere in `otherItem` but in the order of 'item' in your loop. You can use a string like so:

```
>>> print [this for this in list_1 for that in list_2 if stringy(this[0:2]) in stringy(that)]
[[1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]
```

This is different than the set version since `'12'!='21'` and `'12' not in '21'`  So if you changed the order of the elements of list_2:

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 2]]

print [this for this in list_1 for that in list_2 if set(this[0:2])<set(that)]
[[1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]   # same answer since sets are unordered
print [this for this in list_1 for that in list_2 if stringy(this[0:2]) in stringy(that)]
[[1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 8]]              # different answer...
```

Comment: list_1 = [[a,c],[b,q],[e,f],[a,c],[b,e],[b,e]]

new_list = [[a,c,2],[b,q,1],[e,f,1],[b,e,2]]

Comment: @JohnnyC: Help me out here. What does your comment mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
print set([1,2]).intersection([1,2,3])==set([1,2])
```

would be `True`

using set intersection I think you can get what you want

It is important to note that sets are un-ordered collections unique elements

thus `set([1,1,2]) == set([1,2])`
and so this may not necessarily work for you for all instances

Comment: `bool` isn't quite good enough.  `set([1,2]).intersection([1,1,1])` would evaluate to `True` in this context.  See the edit that I was working on when you posted.

Comment: Now this is right -- Although, `__eq__` will give you a bool already, so your `bool` is unnecessary :).  +1