# python - Check if the exact set of values exist in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if the values in a list exist in another list.
For example:

```
list1 = ['a','b']

list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c']

list3 = ['a','a','b','b','b','a','b','a']
```

I want to check if the values in `list1` exist in `list2` & `list 3`. However, the check should return false when I compare with `list2` since `list2` also has other values apart from 'a' & 'b'. And the check should return true when compared with list3 since it has only 'a','b'. any clue how I can do this?

Hope this is clear.

Edit: `set(list1) == set(list3)` Works

Comment: `set(list1) == set(list3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'in' to test for part of one sublist in another in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144009/using-in-to-test-for-part-of-one-sublist-in-another-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sets:

```
>>> set(list1) == set(list2)
False
>>> set(list1) == set(list3)
True
```

Comment: 9 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `all`,

```
In [11]: all(i in list1 for i in list2)
Out[11]: False

In [12]: all(i in list1 for i in list3)
Out[12]: True
```